# How to create and use object with Objective-C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, object

Im programming with objective c for ios. I have a problem...i create a class object
this is the Item.h

```
@interface Item : NSObject {
NSString *date;
NSMutableArray *a;
NSMutableArray *b;
NSMutableArray *c;
NSMutableArray *d;
NSMutableArray *e;
NSMutableArray *f;
NSMutableArray *g;}

- (id)init;
- (void)setDate:(NSString *)dateGio;
- (void)adda:(NSString *)i;
- (void)addb:(NSString *)i;
- (void)addc:(NSString *)i;
- (void)addd:(NSString *)i;
- (void)adee:(NSString *)i;
- (void)addf:(NSString *)i;
- (void)addg:(NSString *)i;
- (NSMutableArray *)geta;
- (NSMutableArray *)getb;
- (NSMutableArray *)getc;
- (NSMutableArray *)getd;
- (NSMutableArray *)gete;
- (NSMutableArray *)getf;
- (NSMutableArray *)getg;
@end
```

and this is the Item.m

```
#import "MealsItem.h"

@implementation MealsItem

- (id)init {
self = [super init];
if(self) {
    NSString *date = @"";
    NSMutableArray *a = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    NSMutableArray *b = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    NSMutableArray *c = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    NSMutableArray *d = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    NSMutableArray *e = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    NSMutableArray *f = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    NSMutableArray *g = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
}
return self;
}

- (void)adda:(NSString *)i {
[a addObject: i];
}

- (void)addb:(NSString *)i {
[b addObject: i];
}

- (void)addb:(NSString *)i {
[b addObject: i];
}

- (void)addd:(NSString *)i {
[d addObject: i];
}

- (void)adde:(NSString *)i {
[e addObject: i];
}

- (void)addf:(NSString *)i {
[f addObject: i];
}

- (void)addg:(NSString *)i {
[g addObject: i];
}

- (NSMutableArray *)geta {
return a;
 }

- (NSMutableArray *)getb {
return b;
}

- (NSMutableArray *)getc {
return c;
}

- (NSMutableArray *)getd {
return d;
}

- (NSMutableArray *)gete {
return e;
}

- (NSMutableArray *)getf {
return f;
}

- (NSMutableArray *)getg {
return g;
}

@end
```

In this object i save string in the specific array. In my First view (the main of the project) i initialize the object

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "Item.h"

@interface First_View : UIViewController {
@public Item *ok;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) Item *ok;

@end
```

and in the .m

```
#import "First_View.h"
#import "Item.h"

@interface First_View ()

@end

@implementation First_View

@synthesize ok;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];

ok = [[Item alloc] init];

}

@end
```

The problem is that i have to read and modify the object initialize in the First_View, using the method of "Item.m", from another class. In the other class i use this

```
First_View *first = [[First_View alloc] init];
```

and i try to modify the object but i cant. I can just if i use also

```
first.ok = [[Item alloc] init];
```

but i dont want to initialize again the object but use the object already created in the First_View. How is possible to modify the object without initialize again the object??

Comment: You are not initializing your ok object because you are doing it in your method viewDidLoad and this method is called when the view of your controller was loaded. overwritte your method init in FirstView and add your initialization of ok object. And if you have XIB, you could to initialize your ok object in the method initWithNibName and to initialize your FirstView with this method and no with init method

Comment: Variable names cannot start with a number. Consider this: if you have a variable named `1`, how would you use the integer `1`? If this was allowed the compiler wouldn't know whether you meant your variable or the integer.

Comment: Thanks @SonGoku68 , I moved the code from viewDidLoad to initWithNibName. But I have another problem now. In a class (not the Fisrt_View) I add some string to the NSMutableArray using one of the set method and this work, but if i try to read, using the get method, from a third class the NSMutableArray is empty. There is the object "Item", but the NSMutableArray inside look like empty again.

Comment: I think your arrays are empty because you are not setting their properties in your .h file. Create your NSMutableArray with nonatomic and strong properties like this: @property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *a;

Comment: I tried to modify the Item.h with @property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *a; ..... but the problem is the same. The data are saved correctly in a second class but in a third other if i read the array this is (are) empty.

Comment: if you array is empty when you use strong attribute mean your ViewController has been deallocated. How are you calling to your third view and from where? Could you attach an image of your storyboard?? it will help me very much

Comment: @SonGoku68 this i the image freeimagehosting . net/newuploads/xwuuz.jpg the number 1 is the First_View where i create the object, then i modify it in a class utility (with no view) and i read the object in the number 3.

Comment: I was right, if you can´t access to objects from First_View from Third_View because when you access to Third_View, First_View is deallocated. They are in differents ways. Copy your array from First_View in your Main_View (Sidebar View Controller) after to load it and try to access to this array from Third_View, you will check as you can.

Comment: @SonGoku68 I moved the init of the Item object in Sidebar View Controller but i have the same problem. In the third class I use SidebarViewController *first = [[SidebarViewController alloc] init]; and [first->ItemName] to access the object, exist but is empty.

Comment: I think you have many gaps in your OOP and Objective-C formation. If you do SidebarViewController *first = [[SidebarViewController alloc] init]; in your first view controller, you are creating a new instance of SidebarViewController, and what you should do is access to your instance created already.

Comment: @SonGoku68 yes I'm new in objective c programming, i know java and now I'm learning obj c. How can I call the object without creating the new instance of SidebarViewController ?

Comment: For a quick checking, create a sideBarViewController property in your appDelegate called sideBarVC, in your viewDidLoad method of your sideBarViewController insert this code `YourAppDelegate *delegate = (YourAppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]; [delegate setSideBarVC:self];` Load your arrays and from Third_View access to your arrays like this: `YourAppDelegate *delegate = (YourAppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]; NSLog(@"Object 0: %@", [delegate.sideBarVC.a objectAtIndex:0]);`

Comment: @SonGoku68 I put the Item object in appDelegate and now work!!! Thanks a lot for the idea!!

Answer (score 2):

The code in Item.m / Item.h doesn't make any sense to me whatsoever.

1. You are trying to declare instance variables named 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7. That's nonsense.
2. You are explicitly declaring getter and setter methods. That's just creating unnecessary work for yourself. Just use @property.
3. Your init method doesn't do what you think it does. It creates new objects, but doesn't assign them to instance variables, but to local variables in the init method. Which means they are lost as soon as init returns. And you tried to name these variables 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 which is illegal and nonsense.
4. Where do "breakfast" etc. come from?

Answer (score 1):

You can use what is known as lazy instantiation. If you declare your arrays as properties,

```
@interface Item : NSObject
@property (strong) NSMutableArray *array;
@end
```

XCode automatically creates the setter and getter for you. The trick is to override the getter as follows:

```
- (NSMutableArray *)array
{
    if (!_array)
    {
        _array = [NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    }
    return _array;
}
```

In that way the array is only instantiated once (or zero times if you never use it – hence the word lazy). Remember that if you want to override both the setter and the getter, you must synthesize the property:

```
@synthesize array = _array
```

Comment: it will be great if you could say how he could use it in his case or give a more details example ;)

Comment: I am having troubles understanding what is going on in OP's code. I would rather suggest that he/she posted a smaller example illustrating exactly what the problem is. That increases the chances of a more precise reply.